# Why is vlc not syncing audio and video correctly?

Tags: audio, video, synchronization, vlc

```
max@linux-vwzy:~> vlc --version
VLC media player 1.1.11 The Luggage (revision exported)
VLC version 1.1.11 The Luggage (exported)
Compiled by abuild on messiah (Aug 17 2011 15:23:16)
Compiler: gcc version 4.5.1 20101208 [gcc-4_5-branch revision 167585] (SUSE Linux) 
This program comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute it under the terms of the GNU General Public License;
see the file named COPYING for details.
Written by the VideoLAN team; see the AUTHORS file.
```

Every file I seem to play requires me to bring the audio back about 0.4 of a second. I would post if this was for a couple video, but this is my entire video library which was encoded in different ways and created at different times. This only seemed to happen when I switched my window manager from KDE to dwm; it worked fine in vlc before that

Comment: @froztbyte This only seemed to happen when I switched my window manager from KDE to dwm. Added to question

Comment: What format are you playing and what the cpu use when playing them?
When you have high cpu use the video will get behind the audio.
I have had this issue on hd quicktime files and h.264 form my sony dlsr.

Comment: So are you using a [sound server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_server) now (PulseAudio or other)?

Comment: @saras, Every format you can imagine

Comment: @Gilles, Is there a way for me to verify? I haven't messed with the default KDE audio options

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1885760#1885760

Answer (score 1):

You didn't indicate if you tested this on another application as well, so the problem might be the sound server you're using. If you're using PulseAudio, it does introduce delays which might be the cause of your problem. Without more info, it isn't really possible to say.

Comment: This only seemed to happenw when I switched window manager from KDE to dwm. It worked fine in vlc before that